# Easiest way to check numbers

Tags: c#, linq

I have a string array. What is the simplest way to check if all the elements of the array are numbers

```
string[] str = new string[] { "23", "25", "Ho" };
```

Comment: please, define number: its a int32, decimal, float-point?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you add a reference to the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` assembly, you can use the following one-liner:

```
bool isEverythingNumeric = 
    str.All(s => Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information.IsNumeric(s));
```

Comment: Clever +1 ... out-of-the-box thinking

Comment: Why use something that seems so specific to VisualBasic?

Comment: Good thinking, however, I don't know if it is worth for the use of 1 function including an entire dll.

Comment: Why is something so generally useful in the VisualBasic assembly? (also see http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode31SingleInstanceWinFormsAndMicrosoftVisualBasicdll.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

You can do this:

```
var isOnlyNumbers = str.All(s =>
    {
        double i;
        return double.TryParse(s, out i);
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
string[] str = new string[] { "23", "25", "Ho" };
double trouble;
if (str.All(number => Double.TryParse(number, out trouble)))
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Nice idea, but this will work only if all the numbers fit inside an Int32.

Answer (score 3):

How about using regular expressions?

```
 using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
 ...
 bool isNum= Regex.IsMatch(strToMatch,"^\\d+(\\.\\d+)?$");
```

[TryParse](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/IsNumeric.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Using the fact that a string is also an array of chars, you could do something like this:

```
str.All(s => s.All(c => Char.IsDigit(c)));
```

Comment: But this will not work with strings that contains white space. And how about scientific notation?

Comment: seems we need to define what's a number first =)

Comment: Kona ... what about -1? That's not a downvote :P Just a question ;)

Comment: Well, that would work with the example provided. Maybe the asker could clarify if he needs to check for non-digit characters?

Answer (score 1):

Or without linq...

```
bool allNumbers = true;
foreach(string str in myArray)
{
   int nr;
   if(!Int32.TryParse(str, out nr))
   {
      allNumbers = false;
      break;
   }
}
```

Comment: Why not using linq? You may continue with writing your own TryParse method:)

Comment: Because our evil boss forces us to use C# 2.0 ;)